# How to associate from a parent model to another

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$user = User::create(['name' => request('name'),
                'email' =>  request('email'),
                'password' => bcrypt(request('password')),
                'place_id' => request('place_id'), 
                'role_id' =>  request('role_id') ,
                'status'  =>  request('status')]);

        if (request('role_id') === 3) {
            $user->courier()->associate($user);  
            $user->save() ; 
        }
```

I want to insert in my couriers table the user_id of that inserted user if it has role_id of 3. I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: Change your code from `===` to `==` Laravel's request object returns strings even though it is an int. Try it out.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'courier_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2018-03-02 11:01:22, `courier_id` = 413 where `id` = 413)

I get something like that

Comment: do you have courier_id in user table?

Comment: No in my couriers table there is a user_id

Comment: so one courier is related to only one user right?

Comment: Yeah one to one relationship only :

Comment: public function courier(){
        return $this->hasOne(Courier::class);
    }

Comment: public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class) ;  
 }

Comment: Sure how would you get courier from above scenario?

Comment: Don't really haave an idea man. I tried someting but did't work

Comment: If you want the way its working now you will have to add courier_id to user table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate the user with a particular courier, there must be the corresponding courier. First of all, you have to find it or create a new courier. If you have `id` of the courier then you can try the following.

```
$courier = Courier::find($user->id);
$courier->user()->associate($user);
$courier->save();
```

The above code will update `user_id` field of the courier with `courier_id` with the id of `$user`

Comment: Yeah your code works. But would it be nice if there's only one pk in the couriers table and that is user_id ?

Comment: Creating default object from empty value. I had thi s error.

Comment: Can you share the whole method?

Comment: Oops i didn't copy your code.. That's why I'm sorry

Comment: Call to a member function user() on null. I still get an error.

Comment: You have to confirm that the user instance successfully created. You can try `dump($user);` after create statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166134/discussion-between-d3cypher-and-nikhil-nediyodath).